# How to iterate over certain lines to match with GNU sed?

Tags: bash, sed, gnu

The following code snippet gives the following error

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 45: unterminated address regex
```

when line number is iterated over:

```
for line in `seq 1 3 265`; do
  sed -i '\${\line\}s/foo/bar/' $FILE
done
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: variables don't interpolate into single-quotes. try replacing `sed -i` with `echo`

Comment: sed allows "\" followed by (almost) any character as regex delimiter instead of `/`. eg. `\x123x` is equivalent to `/123/`

Comment: @jhnc, So what would be a viable solution? Please post it as an answer so I try out and accept.

Comment: Just use: `sed -i $line's/foo/bar/' "$FILE"`

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Answer (score 1):

A couple issues with current code:

- `sed` script must use double quotes in order for `bash` variables to be expanded
- no need for escape character (`\`) ... in this case

A couple small changes to OP's current code:

```
for line in `seq 1 3 265`; do
  sed -i "${line} s/foo/bar/" $FILE
done
```

One `awk` idea that requires a single pass through the input file:

```
awk '
BEGIN      { for (i=1;i<=265;i=i+3) seq[i] }
FNR in seq { $0=gensub(/foo/,"bar",1) }
1' $FILE
```

If using `GNU awk`, and satisfied with the results of this code, replace `awk '...` with `awk -i inplace '...` to facilitate updating the source file.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i '1~3s/foo/bar;265{:a;n;ba}' file
```

From line 1 and every 3 lines thereafter until line 265 substitute `foo` for `bar`.

Or:

```
sed -i '256,$b;1~3s/foo/bar/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do the `seq 1 3 265` skip-count thing without any `modulo %` math at all :

> ```
> jot -w '%d=foobar=barfool=' 265 | 
>
> {m,g}awk 'BEGIN { __ =_^=  FS = "^$"
>           __+=_+_ } NR !=_ || -sub("foo","bar")<(_+=(_<265)*__)'
> ```

`1=`**`barbar`**`=barfool=`

```
2=foobar=barfool=
3=foobar=barfool=
```

`4=`**`barbar`**`=barfool=`

```
5=foobar=barfool=
6=foobar=barfool=
```

`7=`**`barbar`**`=barfool=`

```
8=foobar=barfool=
9=foobar=barfool=
.
.
.`
```